# findViewById - Cannot resolve method

Tags: android, view, android-asynctask

I am new to android programming. This is my first app. I am trying to understand the best practice or way to use Async task.

scenario- I need to get data over HTTP and display it on app home screen.

main Class - Draws some basic stuff on screen and calls Async class.
Async class - get data from strings.xml, send it over http, retrieves content and store the processed content as Enum. N

My question - now when i try to get the table from activity.xml in Async class method, it says Cannot resolve method findViewById.

Is this right way to do? pls help.

Comment: What does your class extend ? View , and classes that extend it have the method in question

Comment: Thanks, wil try extending view...

Answer (score 0):

You should post the code from your Activity and your Async class, that will help us find a solution for your problem faster.

I'm just guessing on what you wrote, but it seems you're trying to access the *findViewById* method inside your Async class, which cannot be done due to *findViewById* being a method from the Activity class, hence it doesn't exist in Async.

You should callback to your UI thread on your Activity to update it.

To do this you should place any changes on the `postExecute` method of your Async class, remember anything done in the `doInBackground` method is done in a different thread. Only then can you apply the desired changes.

Comment: The problem is, i have a Enum as the processed result. this cannot be passed back to Activity from an class extending Async class.

Comment: could you post some code? Are you declaring your Async class inside your Activity class? Are you trying to make changes inside your doInBackground method?

Answer (score -2):

You cannot run UI operations in the background. You should run them in `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate`, like this.

```
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate (String... result)
    {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewRSSI2)).setText(result[0]);
    }
```

Update: in your `AsyncTask` you set three types:

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
```

The first is what you pass to the AsyncTask when executing it, the second is progress units and the third is result units.

When you publish progress, you do something like this in your `doInBackground()`:

```
publishProgress(yourstring);
```

result[0] in the code above will be yourstring.

and for `onPostExecute`, you should `return` a value in your doInBackground:

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    return yourstring }
```

Comment: I like this site, you get voted down but nobody bother to explain why.

Comment: How to get the resultant enum to onPostExecute or onProgressUpdate to populate the table? Any suggestions?